# How to resolve undefined method error for user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path in Devise with Omniauth integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

How to resolve a NameError for Omniauth paths in Rails view?
I'm currently implementing Omniauth authentication in my Rails application. In my view file, I have the following code:

```
<div class="social_login">
  <div class="">
    <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path, type: "button", class: "social_box fb" %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in with Google", user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_path, type: "button", class: "social_box google" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb:

```
 devise_for(:user, {
    class_name: 'Spree::User',
    singular: :spree_user,
    controllers: {
      sessions: 'user_sessions',
      registrations: 'user_registrations',
      passwords: 'user_passwords',
      confirmations: 'user_confirmations',
      omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
    },
```

omniauth_controller.rb:

```
class OmniauthController < ApplicationController
  def facebook
    @user = Spree::User.create_from_provider_data(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user
    else
      flash[:error] = 'There was a problem signing you in through Facebook. Please register or try signing in later.'
      redirect_to new_spree_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def google_oauth2
    @user = Spree::User.create_from_provider_data(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user

    else
      flash[:error] = 'There was a problem signing you in through Google. Please register or try signing in later.'
      redirect_to new_spree_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    flash[:error] = 'There was an error signing you in. Please try again.'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Could someone please guide me on how to correctly reference the Omniauth paths in the view? What should the correct paths be, and how can I ensure they are properly defined?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you want to share the whole error message - to find the missing method and the specific line in the file

Comment: The path helpers should be listed in the `rails routes` output.

Comment: there are no any path there of omniauth, but i defined the controller in routes.rb file @smathy

Comment: how can i resolve it ? @zaphodbln_

Comment: @AfaqKhan: As smathy and I pointed out: Share the whole error message and the output of `rails routes`

Comment: ...and your `routes.rb` file if you think there are routes in there that aren't showing up in `rails routes`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz8by.png   @zaphodbln_

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2BFE.png @smathy